# how to base64 encode a doc file

Tags: php, base64, encode

I am working on a php project that I need to send base64 encoded doc document to the server using CURL. Here is the code:
$c = file_get_contents("test.doc");
$encoded = base64_encode($c);

I found the resulting $encoded is invalid.

In this website: https://www.base64encode.org/
I uploaded the file and base64 encoded online, the resultant encoded string is correct.

I then tried to cut and paste the text from the doc file and encoded them online at the above website, the resultant string is different than the valid string I got.  Therefore, I guess I could not just extract the text from the doc file and base64 encode them.

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
$c =  file_get_contents("test.doc");
file_put_contents('temp.txt',$c);
$cc = file_get_contents('temp.txt');
if(strlen($cc)=='0'){
$cc = fopen("temp.txt","r");}
$encoded = base64_encode($cc);
unlink('temp.txt');
```

Comment: Is this a typo "if(strlen($cc=='0'))", should it be "if(strlen($cc) != 0)"?

Comment: Sorry, it was partially working. I tested originally with a very simple doc file "hello world" and it worked! But I tried a more complicated doc with the above code, I got following errors at the server side:Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)